# How to apply AND operator in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to hide the rows from row index from 1 to 3. The below code is not working:

```
$("table").find("tr:gt(1)").find("tr:lt(3)").each(function () { $(this).hide() });
```

Comment: Can't you use? .odd()? I don't think you need to use .each with .odd()

Comment: @zzzzBov: `gt` and `lt` are 0-based.  http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham, I'm simply asking OP to clarify specifically which range of elements are supposed to be selected. I understand that `:gt` and `:lt` use 0-based indices, but given how OP is misusing `find` I can't assume anything about OP's knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first find() returns the matched elements and then the second one filters that selection further.

Try this selector

```
$('table tr:gt(0):lt(4)').hide();
```

Also, [slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) would be a great option (if not the best)

```
$('table tr').slice(1,4).hide();
```

Comment: These all hide the wrong rows.  The OP wanted to hide index 1-3.  The first hides indexes 2-4, the second hides index 2, and the third hides 0-3.

Comment: Didn´t see anything about indexes in the question but I´ve edited my answer. Thanks

Comment: The indexes reset after the first filter, so you'll want `:gt(0):lt(3)` for the first example.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [the `slice` method](http://api.jquery.com/slice/).

From the docs:

> **Description:** *Reduce the set of matched elements to a subset specified by a range of indices*
>
> **.slice( start [, end] )**
>
> **start** An integer indicating the 0-based position at which the elements begin to be selected. If negative, it indicates an offset from the end of the set.
>
> **end** An integer indicating the 0-based position at which the elements stop being selected. If negative, it indicates an offset from the end of the set. If omitted, the range continues until the end of the set.

Code:

http://jsfiddle.net/tkVut/

```
$("table tr").slice(1, 3 + 1).hide();
```

Also note that [the `hide` method](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) doesn't require you to use `each`:

> Hide the matched elements

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to reduce the matched set of elements to those within the correct range:

```
$("table tr").filter(function(i) {
    return i > 1 && i < 3;
}).hide();
```

Note that I haven't used `each` to iterate over the set of matched elements at the end, because `hide`, like the majority of jQuery methods, applies to all elements in the set anyway.

Comment: This is wrong.  It only includes index 2.  You need `>=` and `<=` for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

A selector like this?

```
$('table tr:gt(0):lt(4)').hide();
```

I can't tell if you inclusively want indices `1` and `3`, so for now I will assume you do.

If you didn't you could use:

```
$('table tr:gt(1):lt(3)').hide();
```

But that would simply be index `2`:

```
$('table tr:eq(2)').hide();
```

If you need to keep `$('table')` as the base selector, you can use the `find` method:

```
$('table').find('tr:gt(#):lt(#)').hide().end().chain().more().stuff()
```

Comment: The first hides all indices > 0.  The second hides 2-4.  The third hides 2 like you said.  The fourth will have the same problem as the others.